# Why does MSDN sample insist on having focus on a list control before calling CListCtrl::GetTopIndex()?

Tags: windows, winapi, user-interface, visual-c++, mfc

[MSDN article on `CListCtrl::GetTopIndex()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wh87k4w%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) contains a code sample that goes like this:

```
// Make sure the focus is set to the list view control.
listControl->SetFocus();

// Select all of the items that are completely visible.
int topIndex = listControl->GetTopIndex();
int lastIndex = listControl+ listControl->GetCountPerPage();

//then there's a for-loop for the items in range from topIndex to lastIndex
```

Why is the comment insisting on the call to `SetFocus()`?

Comment: I'd guess just for presentation reasons because the demo goes on to select items. As with all these calls GetTopIndex is a trivial wrapper for SendMessage [LVM_GETTOPINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms670783.aspx) and there's nothing documented there about focus. But I can't say definitively.

Comment: That code snippet has absolutely no context.  Perhaps it was taken from a larger sample project and they didn't bother to take that line out; who knows.  Unfortunately a lot of MSDN sample code is like this.